# Azure Devops YAML: Looping Jobs With Different Variables Passed

Tags: api, loops, azure-devops, yaml

I am struggling to figure out how to execute an API test using a pipeline where the command used can be modified using a loop. For example:

## TEMPLATE.yaml

```
parameters:
    JobName: ''
    TestDirectory: '.\tests\smoke\'
    PositiveTest: ''
    NegativeTest: ''
    - name: environments
      type: object
      values:
      - dev01
      - dev02
      - test01
      - test02

jobs:
- job: ${{ parameters.JobName }}
  pool:
    name: pool
    demands:
      - Cmd
  variables:
    PosTest: ${{ parameters.PositiveTest }}
    NegTest: ${{ parameters.NegativeTest }}
    Directory: ${{ parameters.TestDirectory }}

  - script: |
      call .\venv\Scripts\activate.bat
      cd $(Directory)
      python $(PosTest)
    displayName: 'Executing Positive Test Scenarios'
    condition: and(succeeded(), ne('${{ variables.PosTest }}', ''))

  - script: |
      call .\venv\Scripts\activate.bat
      cd $(Directory)
      python $(NegTest)
    displayName: 'Executing Negative Test Scenarios'
    condition: and(succeeded(), ne('${{ variables.NegTest }}', ''))
```

## TEST_FILE.yaml

```
...
jobs:
# Get this file: templates\TEMPLATE.yml from the `build` repository (imported above)
- template: templates\api-test-build.yml@build
- ${{ each env in parameters.environments }}:
  parameters:
    TestDirectory: '.\tests\smoke\job_class'
    PositiveTest: 'python_test.py http://apient${{ env }}/arbitrary/api/path/name'
    NegativeTest: ''
```

This of course doesn't work (the each directive returns an error like "the first property must be template". If I move it up a line it then says "the first property must be a job" and this cycle of errors just continues...).

The idea is just that I have a loop that iterates through environment strings (top of the TEMPLATE.yaml example). The yaml file that references the template passes the command `python_test.py http://apient<whatever env string the current iteration is on>/arbitrary/api/path/name` for each iterated string (bottom of TEST_FILE.yaml) and the template just executes each of those api tests. At the end of a run there should be 4 environments that have been tested on.

This is just an idea I have and I am still learned all the in's and out's of Azure Devops YAML. If anyone knows how I can get this to work, any improvements I can make to the idea itself or any other workarounds/solutions that would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [Multi-job configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?tabs=yaml&view=azure-devops#multi-job-configuration) (**`matrix`**) in your pipeline.

When you want to run the same job with multi-configuration in a pipeline, the **`matrix`** strategy is a good choose.

For example, in your pipeline, you want to run the jobs that have the same steps and input parameters but different values of the input parameters. You can just set up one job with the **`matrix`** strategy in the pipeline.